# Firebase: If a value includes a specific text in database

Tags: firebase, rest, firebase-realtime-database

I try to filter the list for items that contain a certain text.

**database:**

```
{"123":{"cities":"sss"},"445":{"cities":"hello hi dd"}}
```

And I want to get the items that contains "hi" within the `cities` value:

```
{"445":{"cities":"hello hi dd"}}
```

I tryd this:

```
https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/allitems.json?orderBy="cities"&startAt="hi"
```

But it's not working... It only shows the items that starts with "hi"...

thanks.

Comment: I think there is no such a function. If that is the case you should get all the data from DB and filter with js. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#methods firebase realtime database is very restrictive and it is designed to work fast. So they are not really flexible in terms of querying

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, there is no built-in full-text search capability in the Firebase Realtime Database.

The official Cloud Functions samples include an [example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fulltext-search) of full-text search with the Algolia hosted search service.

---

Note that there is a workaround if you search for a string that **starts** with some specific characters (which is different than a string which **contains** some specific characters).

Have a look at the "Range Queries" section of the REST API [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#range-queries):

> We can combine `startAt` and `endAt` to limit both ends of our query. The
>   following example finds all dinosaurs whose name starts with the
>   letter "b":
>
> `curl`
>   `'https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs.json?orderBy="$key"&startAt="b"&endAt="b\uf8ff"&print=pretty'`
>
> The `\uf8ff` character used in the query above is a very high code point
>   in the Unicode range. Because it is after most regular characters in
>   Unicode, the query matches all values that start with a `b`.

So in your case you would do as follows:

```
https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/allitems.json?orderBy="cities"&startAt="hi"&endAt="hi\uf8ff"
```